# Whereare the shortcut settings for audio/video actions stored?

Tags: keyboard, gnome, settings, multimedia

I'm trying to find the file where gnome stores the configuration for keybindings, such as Volume Up, Volume Down, in order to get their actions.

I know I can find SOME shortcuts in `$HOME/.gconf/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/%gconf.xml` and `$HOME/.gconf/apps/metacity/window_keybindings/%gconf.xml`, but where are the multimedia keybindings?

Answer (score 4):

The multimedia keybindings are stored in `$HOME/.gconf/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/keybindings/%gconf.xml`. But note that this directory only exists if you changed any of the values -- keys with their default value (e.g. `play = XF86Audioplay`) are not stored. Default values for the multimedia keys are stored in a so called schema file (for details see the [gconf documentation](http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/index.html)):

```
/usr/share/gconf/schemas/apps_gnome_settings_daemon_keybindings.schemas
```

That said: If all you want to do is get the actions associated with a certain keybinding, you should never have to use the files directly. Instead, query the gconf database with a command like this:

```
gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/keybindings/play
```

To get the default value (and other details about the key), you have to query the schema:

```
gconftool-2 --get /schemas/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/keybindings/play
```

Comment: ... or, if you just want to explore, use the GUI: `gconf-editor`, aka "Configuration Editor"

Comment: I need to find out which is the default action of the 'Volume up/down' from System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Multimedia..

Comment: Well, doesn't the answer provide what you need? `gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/keybindings/volume_down` will show the action for "Volume Up" (`XF86AudioLowerVolume`), same for "Volume Down".

Comment: No, the answer doesn't give me what I want. It gives me my keybinding, not the default one.

Comment: @ksemeks: It would have helped if you asked for that in your question... Either way, my answer already mentioned that the default values are stored in the schema file `/usr/share/gconf/schemas/apps_gnome_settings_daemon_keybindings.schemas` -- I updated my answer with the `gconftool` command to query the schema.